# Laravel - Validate at least one field from an array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this data:

```
[2022-12-07 11:56:19] local.INFO: array (
  'name' => NULL,
  'import_period' => NULL,
  'google_ads_account' => NULL,
  'period' => NULL,
  'period_date_from' => NULL,
  'period_date_to' => NULL,
  'id_campaigns' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id_campaign' => NULL,
    ),
  ),
  'id_adgroups' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id_adgroup' => NULL,
    ),
  ),
  'campaign_name_contains' => NULL,
  'adgroup_name_contains' => NULL,
  'click' => 'less_than',
  'click_value' => NULL,
  'click_from' => NULL,
  'click_to' => NULL,
  'impressions' => 'less_than',
  'impressions_value' => NULL,
  'impressions_from' => NULL,
  'impressions_to' => NULL,
  'cost' => 'less_than',
  'cost_value' => NULL,
  'cost_from' => NULL,
  'cost_to' => NULL,
  'conversions' => 'less_than',
  'conversions_value' => NULL,
  'conversions_from' => NULL,
  'conversions_to' => NULL,
  'mapping_list' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'conversions',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'roas',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'all_conversions',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'all_conversions_from_interactions_rate',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'ctr',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'average_cpc',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'clicks',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'impressions',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'cost',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'conversions_value',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'conversions_from_interactions_rate',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'cost_per_conversion',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    12 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'search_click_share',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    13 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'search_impression_share',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    14 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'value_per_all_conversions',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
    15 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'value_per_conversion',
      'text' => NULL,
    ),
  ),
)
```

**I am validating this data like this:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name'                      =>  'required',
    'import_period'             =>  'required',
    'google_ads_account'        =>  'required',
    
    'period'                    =>  'required',
    'period_date_from'          =>  'required_if:period,custom', 
    'period_date_to'            =>  'required_if:period,custom',

    'id_campaigns.*.id_campaign'=>  'required',
    'id_adgroups.*.id_adgroup'  =>  'required',
    'campaign_name_contains'    =>  'required',
    'adgroup_name_contains'     =>  'required',
    'mapping_list.*.text'       =>  'required|min:1',

    'click'                     =>  'required',
    'click_value'               =>  'required_if:click,greater_than,less_than',
    'click_from'                =>  'required_if:click,between',
    'click_to'                  =>  'required_if:click,between',

    'cost'                      =>  'required',
    'cost_value'                =>  'required_if:cost,greater_than,less_than',
    'cost_from'                 =>  'required_if:cost,between',
    'cost_to'                   =>  'required_if:cost,between',

    'impressions'               =>  'required',
    'impressions_value'         =>  'required_if:impressions,greater_than,less_than',
    'impressions_from'          =>  'required_if:impressions,between',
    'impressions_to'            =>  'required_if:impressions,between',

    'conversions'               =>  'required',
    'conversions_value'         =>  'required_if:conversions,greater_than,less_than',
    'conversions_from'          =>  'required_if:conversions,between',
    'conversions_to'            =>  'required_if:conversions,between',

]);
```

Here on this line `'mapping_list.*.text'       =>  'required|min:1'` I am trying to validate this `mapping_list` array.

**I want at least one field should be filled up but I have to fill up every element of this array.**

Can you tell me is there anyting I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate that at least one field is filled, you must specify which field you want to validate. For example (in your code):

`'mapping_list.*.text'       =>  'required|min:1',`

you can change

`'mapping_list.[0].text'       =>  'required|min:1',`

or

`'mapping_list.[1].text'       =>  'required|min:1',`

That should be all you need to do. Hopefully that helps!